# How to get my private keys for my K8S Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ssh

Last year, I built a K8S cluster on AWS with [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)

Now, One year after, I don't remember which are the private keys. I must connect my VM through SSH, but I don't remember where I have put the PK on my local machine. Is there anyway to find the location of the PK ?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to a Kubernetes cluster usually has nothing to do with SSH keys. In order to be able to execute commands onto a Kubernetes cluster you need to have a `kubeconfig` which will be used by `kubectl`.
In case you are searching for your `kubeconfig` it is usually located at `~/.kube/config` but the path can vary depending onto your setup (you can set the path to anything by defining an environment variable like so: `export KUBECONFIG=/some/path/to/a/kubeconfig`).

SSH keys on the other hand are stored in a hidden folder called `.ssh` inside your home directory (`~/.ssh/`). In there you will find both private and public keys; public keys usually end on `.pub`.
In case you do not have a `~/.ssh/` directory check other users on your machine, perhaps you created them for the root user.
Other than that you might also want to check your `history` as the private key location can also be specified with `ssh -i` as in `ssh -i /path/to/private_key user@remote-machine`, perhaps you saved it somewhere else and specified the key that way.